# how to tell the UI to change the Values to a computed property

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

usually in iOS i will do a `didSet` but Kotlin does not provide the same, how can I do Such a thing.

`

```
val dnValues = stringArrayResource(R.array.dn_values_array)

val pnValuesSteel = stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_full)
val pnValuesGray = stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_gray_iron)
val pnValuesDuctile = stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_ductile_iron)

var pnValues = pnValuesGray

val materialValues = stringArrayResource(R.array.materials_array)

val newMaterial: (String) -> Unit = { material ->

    when (material) {
        materialValues[0] -> {
            pnValues = pnValuesGray
        }

        materialValues[1] -> {
            pnValues = pnValuesDuctile
        }

        materialValues[2] -> {
            pnValues = pnValuesSteel
        }
    }
}`
```

when I debug the code I see the pnValues change the way I want, but the UI never refresh on the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the previous comments, because the Values get stuck on the remembered ones and the Custom picker won't work.

```
val dnValues = stringArrayResource(R.array.dn_values_array)

val pnValuesSteel = stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_full)
val pnValuesGray = stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_gray_iron)
val pnValuesDuctile =  stringArrayResource(R.array.pn_values_array_ductile_iron)

val materialValues = stringArrayResource(R.array.materials_array)

var assignedMaterial by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

val newMaterial: (String) -> Unit = { material ->

    when (material) {
        materialValues[0] -> {
            assignedMaterial = material
        }

        materialValues[1] -> {
            assignedMaterial = material
        }

        materialValues[2] -> {
            assignedMaterial = material
        }
    }
}
```

what I did was, just removing the pnValuesSteel, Gray, Ductile  and set the correct one depending on the material which I retrieve from the chosen one on the picker. setting the pnValuesSteel, Gray, Ductile (values) I have done it in the same scope where it should be assigned. see below

```
        CircularList(
                    width = 60.dp,
                    itemHeight = 50.dp,
                    items = when (assignedMaterial) {
                        materialValues[0] -> {
                            pnValuesGray
                        }

                        materialValues[1] -> {
                            pnValuesDuctile
                        }

                        materialValues[2] -> {
                            pnValuesSteel
                        }
                        else ->{
                            pnValuesGray
                        }
                    }
```

now it works perfectly.

any comments on the solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following variable declaration:

```
var pnValues by remember { mutableStateOf(pnValuesGray) }
```

If you assign a new value to `pnValues`, the UI should change accordingly. In Jetpack Compose, you need to `remember` all variables that the Composables should observe the changes from. 
Also see the documentation about [State in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables).

Comment: thanks but that did not work as I have tried, because the Values get stuck on the remembered one and the Custom picker won't work 

no I made it work with a better solution thanks I will post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just like [BenjyTec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331157/benjytec) answered.

1. You have to declare the `pnValues` as MutableState.
2. Your Composable has to use the value from `pnValues`.

```kotlin
var pnValues by remember { mutableStateOf(pnValuesGray) }

//makes your composable observe the value from pnValues
YourComposable(pnValues)

@Composable
fun YourComposable(value: String) {
    Text(value)
}
```

Then whenever `pnValues` changed its value, the `Text` composable will recompose with the latest value.

Comment: thanks but that did not work as I have tried, because the Values get stuck on the remembered one and the Custom picker won't work 

no I made it work with a better solution thanks I will post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how JetPack Compose works.
In most cases, you no longer update variables and states by methods (update, set, get, etc.).

Instead, there are mutableStates - `val myState = mutableStateOf</variable type/>(/initial state value, such as from a constructor/)`

Docs for states in JetPack Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#managing-state

Any change to the variable `myState` updates the UI whenever you subscribe to it, by using it for example in `Text(modifier = Modifier.background(color = myState.value))`.

The value can be then changed by anything you desire.

Easiest example of variable change would be from a button click, as following:

```
   Button(
        onClick = {
             myState.value = /whatever value you declared in the mutableStateOf/
        }
   ) {
        Text(text = "Click me to update variable")
   }
```

In case of some variable coming from API, which should update our variable, use

```
   LaunchedEffect(/to what change are we subscribing? - such as viewModel.variableX.value/) { 
        viewModel.variableX.collect {  
              myState.value = /whatever value you declared in the mutableStateOf/
        }
   }
```

Docs for LaunchedEffect: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect

Note, that any UI change will also change all the variables into their initial states because they are not labeled as *remembered*.
Such thing is crucial when using mutableStates.
It can be achieved as following:

```
val myState = remember(/on what variable is the remember broken - such as value from a constructor/) { 
       mutableStateOf</variable type/>(/initial state value, such as from a constructor/)
}
```

Docs for State holders: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders